# Error when adding one to interval

Tags: python, local

So here's my code:

```
from sympy.solvers import nsolve
from sympy import Symbol

def solver(I):
    return nsolve(x-3*(1-2.73**-x), I, verify=False)

i_min=-51
i_max=100
z=0
x = Symbol('x')
for i in range(i_min,i_max):
    y=z
    z=solver(i)
    if y!=z: continue
    print(z)
```

When I run this it works as expected. If I change `i_min` to `-52` though, it doesn't work and I get:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

Combing through other answers about this error, I saw that most suggest using global variables. But so far any global variable declaration I've tried hasn't worked.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here's the entire log:

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-3-1dfdd15c7bf8> in <module>()
     11 for i in range(i_min,i_max):
     12     y=z
---> 13     z=solver(i,x)
     14     if y!=z: continue
     15     print(z)

<ipython-input-3-1dfdd15c7bf8> in solver(I, x)
      3 
      4 def solver(I,x='x'):
----> 5     return nsolve(x-3*(1-2.73**-x), I, verify=False)
      6 
      7 i_min=-55

/home/... in nsolve(*args, **kwargs)
   2752 
   2753         f = lambdify(fargs, f, modules)
-> 2754         return findroot(f, x0, **kwargs)
   2755 
   2756     if len(fargs) > f.cols:

/home... in findroot(ctx, f, x0, solver, tol, verbose, verify, 
**kwargs)
    965             if error < tol * max(1, norm(x)) or i >= maxsteps:
    966                 break
--> 967         if not isinstance(x, (list, tuple, ctx.matrix)):
    968             xl = [x]
    969         else:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Move the four declaration statements (`i_min=-51`, `i_max=100`, `z=0`, `x = Symbol('x')`) to before (above) the `def` statement.

Comment: Is there any reason why you _cant_ give the local variables as arguments to the defined function? Relying on variables from the outside scope should be avoided when possible.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid To  my understanding, the order of `function` `definitions` doesn't matter...

Comment: Indeed changing the order has no effect. I could do what @MatsLindh you suggest, but nothing changes.

Comment: Updates SymPy and mpmath. I can't reproduce the error with SymPy 1.1.1 and mpmath 1.0 but I get the error with Sympy 1.0 and mpmath 0.19. It looks like a bug in the mpmath module

Comment: @FJSevilla That did the trick, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Simply pass `x` into the `solver` function as a `parameter`. This way you are not relying on `global` `variables`.

The `code` for doing this may look something like:

```
from sympy.solvers import nsolve
from sympy import Symbol    

def solver(I, x):
    return nsolve(x-3*(1-2.73**-x), I, verify=False)

i_min=-51
i_max=100
z=0
x = Symbol('x')
for i in range(i_min,i_max):
    y=z
    z=solver(i, x)
    if y!=z: continue
    print(z)
```

Comment: Indeed this is a workaround `global variables`, but I still get the same error when I ran the code.

Comment: @George I don't see why you would, you mentioned it worked when `i_min` was `-51` but not when it was `-52` - this seems suspicious, please elaborate...

Comment: This code prints the right solution for an interval between 2 and 16. After that the solutions are wrong. That's why one needs to provide an initial guess. Now I want to use a grid to avoid having to provide an initial guess. So I tried with one [-100,100]. That didn't work and gave the error I mentioned. Then I narrowed it down to -52. With Thomas Junk's solution it breaks down at -55.

Comment: @George sorry, I'm not familiar with `sympy` so can'y help you out on `library` specific things...

Answer (score 1):

From what your code looks *now*

you could easily rewrite it to:

```
def solver(I, x='x'):
    return nsolve(x-3*(1-2.73**-x), I, verify=False)
```

Comment: Using this modification I get:  TypeError: name should be a string, not <class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>

Comment: forget about Symbol ;) I do not know any `sympy` it was just a guess, from what you wrote.

Comment: With your solution it now breaks down at -55 instead of -52. Same error as before.

Comment: oh. That means, you have an error down there and not in here.